# Why is every conformal automorphism of the first complex quadrant a Mobius Transform?

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

I know the conformal automorphisms of the upper half plane are mobius transforms but I am stuck on using this to prove this statement. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your title says first quadrant but the body of your question says upper half plane. These are not the same question. I assume the first answer below is in response to the title.

Comment: Well I assumed you'd use that and the fact that the two are biholomorphic to prove it but I realised I was wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not.  You get things like $\sqrt{z^2+1}$.

However, it is true that every conformal automorphism can be written as $\sqrt{F(z^2)}$ where $F$ is a conformal automorphism of the upper half plane.

Comment: Oh ok, interesting, but why is that? Is it a result of the fact $z \rightarrow z^2$ maps $Q_1$ to $\mathbb{H}$?